# how to write trigger for bulk records

Tags: trigger, bulkification

I tried this by using this inserting, updating employee record. My task is if employee test__c is equal to contact__c test__c employee is automatically created as that contact child if no contact with that test__c value update null in employee.

It's working when we insert or update in salesforce Ui. If I try in data loader I get this error:

> CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY:fillValueInChild: execution of beforeInsert
>   caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
>   Trigger.fillValueInChild: line 13, column 1

```
trigger fillValueInChild on Employee__c (before insert, before update) {

    Map<decimal,Contact> valsFound = New Map<decimal,Contact>();

    for(employee__c emp : trigger.new){
        for(Contact c : [select id,test__c from contact where test__c =:emp.test__c]) {
            valsFound.put(c.test__c,c);
        }
    }

    for(employee__c emp : trigger.new) {

        if(valsFound.size()>0) {
            emp.contact__c = valsFound.get(emp.test__c).id;
        } else {
            emp.test__c = null;
            emp.contact__c = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First: you are asking how to write trigger for bulk records and you have a query in a loop. That's a really bad practice and is certainly NOT bulkified. Read about it [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices)(*Best Practice #2*)

Second: your problem arises on this line:

```
emp.contact__c = valsFound.get(emp.test__c).id;
```

Reason being that if you try to `get` something from a map with a key that doesn't exist in a map you will get `null` back. And calling `.id` on `null` results in `Attempt to de-reference a null object`. A possible way to fix it would be adding a check that this key exists:

```
if(valsFound.size()>0 && valsFound.containsKey(emp.test__c)) {
    emp.contact__c = valsFound.get(emp.test__c).id;
} else {
```

Comment: The `size` check adds absolutely nothing here. Otherwise nice answer. +1 for `containsKey`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson yes, you're right. I just copied and extended OPs code

Answer (score 0):

```
emp.contact__c = valsFound.get(emp.test__c).id;
```

this line is problematic. 
valsFound.get(emp.test__c) returns null so it becomes null.id and this throws attempt to de-reference null object error

you should change it like this;

```
if(valsFound.get(emp.test__c) != null) emp.contact__c = valsFound.get(emp.test__c).id;
```

Comment: hi i tried but while save code showing error in this statement if(valsFound(emp.test__c) != null) error:Method does not exist or incorrect signature: valsFound(Decimal) at line 12 column 8

Comment: I've fixed it. Try it again please.

Comment: yes its working but records updating when we update in salesforce ui if i used dataloader records not updating test__C field i need to update bulk records using data loader